# I have problems declaring and Argument VB

Tags: vb.net

I have some code in my vb page and I am running into problems with it.

Here is the code

```
    'Vnesi proizvod
    Try
        'Kreiraj adapter 
        Dim TA As New POSDSTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter

        'Vnesi proizvod
        TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, SellPrice, BuyPrice)

        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

And i get This ERROR :

> Error  1   Argument not specified for parameter 'Tax' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Insert(Barcode As Integer?, ItemName As String, BuyPrice As Decimal?, SellPrice As Decimal?, Tax As Integer?) As Integer'. C:\Users\User\Desktop\prodazba\POS\POS\GUI\AddItem.vb   71  13  POS

Comment: the error message describes 5 items: Barcode, ItemName, BuyPrice, SellPrice, Tax.  Your `Ta.Insert` call is passing only 4.  And the datatype for the first is wrong - turn on Option Strict

Comment: ...also, the Insert function wants them in the order listed in the error message (and which VS should show you when typing code).  Your code is passing SellPrice and BuyPrice in the wrong order.  Thats very bad for profit margins.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicate that these are the arguments of the function

```
(Barcode As Integer?, ItemName As String, BuyPrice As Decimal?, SellPrice As Decimal?, Tax As Integer?)
```

But you are passing these arguments

```
TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, SellPrice, BuyPrice)
```

You need to pass the same arguments in the same order

```
TA.Insert(barcode, itemname, buyprice, sellprice, tax)
```

Also, barcode is an integer. If TextBox1 is the barcode, then you'll need to convert it to an integer. If you don't have a tax, I assume you can pass 0.

```
TA.Insert(Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text), TextBox2.Text, buyprice, sellprice, 0)
```